# Codeigniter - passing multiple data arrays to a view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a dropdown menu on an events page with a list of locations.

What I wish to do is retrieve all names from a locations table, store them in an array in my event.php controller, pass this to a view which then lists all the locations in a dropdown menu.

Here is the loop in my controller which retrieves the locations..

```
$result = $this->locationModel->get_locations_list();
$arr[] = '';
foreach ($result as $val)
    $arr[$val->id] = $val->name;
```

I am already passing a variable to my view called $data like so -  `$this->template->load('admin/template', 'admin/eventEdit', $data);`

I have tried passing the $arr variable and the $data array in the above line but this stops the view from rendering.

Please could someone guide me on how to pass the information that is stored in the $arr variable to my view along with the $data variable.

Thanks

Dan

Thanks
Dan

New Code

Controller

```
foreach ($result as $val){ $arr[$val->id] = $val->id; } 
$data['navarr'] = $arr;
```

View 
`<?php foreach($navarr as $value) { $html .= '<option value="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['name'].'</option>'; } echo $html; ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say

```
$data['navarr'] = $arr;
```

And then in the view you will have a variable called `navarr` to use which will be the array.

Change your controller code to

```
// I assume you want $val->id and $val->name
foreach ($result as $val){ $arr[$val->id] = $val->name; } 
$data['navarr'] = $arr;
```

Assuming I'm reading your code correctly, you need to extract the key / value pairs from the array like so:

```
<?php
    foreach($navarr as $key => $value)
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Josh,

That helped me, now im stuck on something else.
In my table I have 3 records

1  The Ritz Manchester   
2  Manor Park    
12  test

The dropdown is now populated but just with the id's how do I also retrieve the name and set that as the value?

Also the third option only reads '1' currently, rather than 12? strange. 
Here is my code..

Controller

foreach ($result as $val){
  $arr[$val->id] = $val->id;
 }
 $data['navarr'] = $arr;

View
 <?php foreach($navarr as $value) {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$value['id'].'">'.$value['name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $html;
    ?>

Comment: @Dan C: It's not an etiquette issue, it's just hard to read in comments. :)

Comment: @Dan C: I think you have a typo in the controller code, update and see if that works. Also note the code I wrote to extract the id (option `value`) and name.